# clearInterval not stopping my counter in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to use a `setInterval` and a `clearInterval` within `useEffect` React hook. The timer starts as expected, but it won't stop.
I am assigning `setInterval` to `intervalID` then calling `clearInterval(intervalID)`

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`isRunning changed to: ${state.isRunning}`); //isRunning changed to: start
    let intervalID;
    console.log(`initial interval is: ${intervalID}`); // initial interval is: undefined
    if (state.isRunning === "start") {
      intervalID = setInterval(() => {
        console.log(`interval is: ${intervalID}`); // interval is: 7
        console.log(`tic toc`);
        dispatch({ type: "tic-toc" });
      }, 1000);
    } else if (state.isRunning === "stop") {
      console.log("clearInterval stop!"); // when I set isRunning to stop, this log shows in the console, but the next line doesn't stop the timer.
      clearInterval(intervalID);
    }
  }, [state.isRunning]);
```

full code: https://github.com/LazaroFilm/pomodoro

Comment: How would that code ever reach the else branch after the interval is started? And if you call the callback again, it can't access the previously stored intervalid because it's local to the callback

Comment: @derpirscher Should I use useState or useReducer to store intervalID? [EDIT] It worked! I used `useState` to store the intervalID. Thanks!

Comment: I have no experience with react so I don't know what useState or useReducer are, but you must store your intervalid outside of this callback to be able to use it again later

Comment: I'm not super experienced with Hooks but I'm pretty sure that [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) is the correct way to persist things like this in a function component. (In a class component you would just use an instance property.)

Answer (score 17):

I think you neither need to use `useState` nor `useRef` hooks for the `intervalID`. Declare it outside the `useEffect` but clear the interval in the cleanup function of the `useEffect` hook like so

```
let intervalID;
useEffect(() => {
    if (isRunning) {
      intervalID = setInterval(() => {
        dispatch({ type: "tic-toc" });
      }, 1000);
    }
      return () => clearInterval(intervalID);
  }, [isRunning]);
```

Whenever `isRunning` changes the component will unmount, and the cleanup function will be executed. So, if the `isRunning` has changed to `false` then the timer should stop at the unmount, and when it's mounted again the condition in the if statement won't be met to run the setInterval, and thus the timer remains stopped. In my code I assumed `isRunning` is boolean (which is the way I prefer it to be), and assumed it's "destructured" from the `state` which I assume comes from `useReducer` hook.

Comment: So that's what cleanup is! I kept reading about it, but never understood until your comment! Thank you it works perfectly! Yes, isRunning is from my `useReducer` and I had it as a string switching between `"start"` and `"stop"` after many desperate attempts with booleans (the boolean wasn't the issue, but I had to try something). I have now moved it back to a boolean.

Comment: Update: this error shows up, turns out it's better to keep `let intervalID;` inside `useEffect()` and it works great! ```Assignments to the 'intervalID' variable from inside React Hook useEffect will be lost after each render. To preserve the value over time, store it in a useRef Hook and keep the mutable value in the '.current' property. Otherwise, you can move this variable directly inside useEffect  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps```

Comment: @VictorLazaro Keeping it local works fine as long as you don't need to clear the interval from anywhere else in the component.

Comment: @VictorLazaro You meant a warning not error, right? It doesn't matter if it loses its value, because if the component rerenders, it means the `isRunning` state variable has changed, which means that either `intervalID` will be set again if `isRuning` is true, or it's not assigned if `isRunning` is false. Keeping it outside enables you to clear the interval from anywhere in the component.

Comment: Gotcha. For this, I did needed it to reset to not counting when the state changed back so that wired perfect. But i see what you mean about keeping it outside.

Answer (score 4):

SOLVED: As @derpirscher pointed out, my intervalID is only local, I had to store it in a `useState` hook to be able to access it later.

```
  const [intervalID, setInterID] = useState(); // created a useState for intervalID

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`isRunning changed to: ${state.isRunning}`);
    console.log(`initial interval is: ${intervalID}`);
    if (state.isRunning === "start") {
      let letintervalID = setInterval(() => {
        console.log(`interval is: ${intervalID}`);
        console.log(`tic toc`);
        dispatch({ type: "tic-toc" });
      }, 1000);
      setInterID(letintervalID); // took letintervalID and stored it in useState intervalID
    } else if (state.isRunning === "stop") {
      console.log("clearInterval stop!");
      clearInterval(intervalID);
    }
  }, [state.isRunning]);
```