# Fetch returns null but after page refresh returns object. How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of 500 posts id. I need to get an array of the first 100 posts. So I do the following:

```
API
https://github.com/HackerNews/API
BASE_URL = 'https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0'

    const checkResponse = (response: Response) => {
      return response.ok ? response.json() : Promise.reject(`Some error`);
    };
    
    const fetchStoryIdList = async (): Promise<any> => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/newstories.json`);
        const idJson: number[] = await checkResponse(response);
        return idJson;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    
        const fetchStoryList = async () => {
          const idList = await fetchStoryIdList(); // idList is an array of 500 ids
        
          const promises: IStory[] = idList.slice(0, 100).map(async (id: number) => {
            try {
              const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/item/${id}.json`);
              const storyData: IStory = await checkResponse(response);
              return storyData;
            } catch (err) {
              console.log(err);
            }
          });
        
          const storyList = await Promise.all(promises);
          console.log('storyList:', storyList);
        
          return storyList;
        };
```

**Problem**

Sometimes API call for a single post data returns null. So I get an array of posts and null. Then its renders in component and crashes because of null. After app crashes I manually refresh page and API calls fire again but this time everyting is fine.

For exapmple fetch request for post with id 28359987 returns null but after I refresh page new Api call returns post for the same id...after a while a get null again for another id...then refresh page and null is gone. How to fix that?

[image]

Comment: Please provide the BASE_URL, fetchStoryIdList function for replication purposes. And maybe the component where you are doing this API call. Your code seems to be fine, so I assume the problem comes from the API.

Comment: Why don't configure your server to just return the paginated list of items that you need?

Comment: In what situation would your api return null, and not an error?

Comment: @BesnikKorça I added BASE_URL as well as fetchStoryIdList function

Comment: @Andy might be because it's not my server?

Comment: it's somewhat unclear what kind of solution you want. If the target server is responding incorrectly, and you don't control it... all you can do is deal with the response. That could mean... skipping nulls, or re-requesting them. Network errors do occur, so you should be prepared to handle them anyway.

Comment: @KevinB so should I handle this problem when rendering? I mean add condition something like  story !== null && render it. Is that correct?

Comment: That is certainly one way of handling it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have had an api error where it fails for a certain request. Although as can be seen in this codesandbox example - it's always working https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-knuth-dbldy?file=/src/App.tsx

As for removing the null value you can append .filter(Boolean) since the null results are useless to you

```
// don't forget those () around await
const storyList = (await Promise.all(promises)).filter(Boolean)
```

Comment: Thank you! Just one more question. I need to do auto refresh. I do it with setInterval in useEffect every minute. Is that correct way to make 100 requests every minute? Or should I check if there's new ids and then make a 100 requests?

Comment: @qweezz **1.) If you have control over the server-side**, it would make sense to check for updates first in order to minimize network traffic. If there is no update, just send short message over network (for example: 0) wich you catch on your client-side with a condition. If there is an update, send the 100 ids instead (hence: 1 single request only)  **2.) If you do not have control over server-side**, then you would have to make that check from your client-side, hence 2 requests instead of 1 - in that case, I would suggest just to fetch the 100 ids in order to have just 1 single request.

Comment: also don't forget to clear the interval when the component unmounts - refer to this in case you don't know how to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64406295/clearinterval-not-stopping-my-counter-in-useeffect