# React clock glithing after changing timezone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a React app that will show time and weather based on user input.
To get weather data I send API request containing a name of the city to openweathermap and it returns json containing coordinates(lat, long) which I then use to make another request to ipgeolocation API to get the timezone of this coordinates.

Clock.jsx

```
const Clock = (props) => {

    const [clock, setClock] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
        setInterval(() => {
            let time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { timeZone: props.timezone });
            setClock(time)
            console.log(time)
            console.log(clock)
        }, 1000);
    })

    return (
        <div className={props.className}>
            {clock}
        </div>
    )
}
```

After cahnging the timezone by making new API request time starts glitching. It frequently changes values between old and new time. What could be the problem?

console.log(time)
[image: console.log(time):]

console.log(clock)
[image: console.log(clock)]

Comment: You need to return a clearInterval on the useEffect() i think. Otherwise, the old useEffect interval will still be there with the new one. Something like this may be https://stackoverflow.com/a/64406606/1437261

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a couple of issues:

First, you're creating a new interval on every render of the component, because you're not populating the right dependencies in useEffect. Since you're depending on `props.tinmezone` to update the interval, it should be added to the dependency array. To fix this, you can add `props.timezone` to useEffect's dependency array.

Second, you're not clearing the interval in your cleanup part of the useEffect. To fix this, return `clearInterval()` in useEffect.

Here's a working code snippet fixing both issues

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      let time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString("en-US", {
        timeZone: props.timezone
      });
      setClock(time);
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [props.timezone]);
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. Guess I should've read about setInterval() before using it.